# Show String together with text in Localnotification

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, uilocalnotification

i guess my problem isn't a tough one.

I'm working on a local notification.

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"%@ additional text",[self nameTextField].text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

so far it works all as expected, but the `Alertbody` just shows `<null> "additional text"`

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, try

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ additional text", [self nameTextField].text];
```

The way you're doing is to show string literals but will not work with variables.

I'm actually surprised the compiler let you get away with that.